# How to preset (programmatically) the filter value in primeng datatable

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

Using angular (4.1.3) and primeng (4.0.3) datatable I need to set the filter value (e.g. from URL parameter).

There is a pretty good docu on custom filters by primeng (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/filter). 
I've tried to implement it similarly with a primeng InputText component as a custom filter:

```
<p-dataTable 
      [value]="licenses" scrollable="true"
      exportFilename="licenses" 
      sscrollHeight="60vh" [paginator]="true" [rows]="20"  [pageLinks]="10" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20,50,100,999999]" #dt>

        <p-column [style]="{'width':'180px'}" [sortable]="true" field="customerId" header="Customer ID" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="contains" filterPlaceholder="Search">

          <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
            <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="custFilter" style="width:100%" (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value,col.field,col.filterMatchMode)" class="ui-column-filter"/>
          </ng-template>

        </p-column>

        ...

</p-dataTable>
```

Now I have an input field, which looks like the "regular" one and even has a "custFilter" model from my component as pre-selected filter value.

The only issue is, this custom filter does not work. It just does not filter regardless of which value I enter (in opposite to the "regular" primeng datatable filter). 
[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzEGm.png)

Answer (score 3):

While further debugging the type script code I have found a way to do the filtering. The input should be like following:

```
<input #filtr type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="custFilter" style="width:100%" (input)="dt.filter($event.srcElement.value,col.field,col.filterMatchMode);" class="ui-column-filter"/>
```

The main difference is, the (input) instead of (onChange) and "$event.srcElement.value" instead of just "$event.value"

Furthermore to achieve initial filtering after the page and data is initially loaded an input event has to be dispatched from within an according component:

```
...
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
...
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(('dt')) dt: DataTable;
  @ViewChild(('filtr')) filtr: ElementRef;
    private initData(): void {
        this.dataService
          .getData()
          .then(data => {
            this.data = data;

            //After the data is loaded, the filtering has to be triggered.
            //A timeout is needed to avoid weird browser console logs if data isn't fully loaded into datatable yet before filtering
            setTimeout(() => {
              //console.log(this.filtr);
              var event = new Event('input', {
                  'bubbles': true,
                  'cancelable': true
              });
              this.filtr.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);

              //One could also call "filter" directly instead of dispatching an input event
              //Working example: this.dt.filter(this.custFilter,"customerId", "contains"); 
              //But emmiting an event seems to be better, because no filterMatchMode has to be 
              //hardcoded and is taken from template
            }, 50); 
          }).catch(this.handleError);
      }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.initLicenses();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set global filter of p-table then the following steps will help:

1. `import { TableModule, Table } from 'primeng/table';`
2. `@ViewChild('mytable') public dataTable: Table;`
3. Table name: set some name in HTML page like:

```
<p-table #mytable [columns]="scrollableCols" [(first)]="tablePageNumber" 
[value]="priceDiffApiData" [frozenColumns]="frozenCols" [scrollable]="true" 
[paginator]="true" [rows]="10" frozenWidth="{{FrozenColsWidth}}px" 
(onPage)="paginate($event)" [globalFilterFields]="cols">
```

4. Inside, set delay of 1 seconds to have `viewchild` element read the object after binding:

```
ngOnInit(){
setTimeout(() => {
            //set filter value of table
            if (this.dataTable !== undefined) {
                this.dataTable.filterGlobal('searchKey', 'contains');   }
        }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: what does dataTable relate to?  jI would expect the <p-table #ttt to be <p-table #dataTable..  is that correct or is the dataTable referencing the p-table in a different way?

Comment: Yes in typescript file you may refer to this.dataTable. Below is code  @ViewChild('ttt') public dataTable: Table; #ttt is name refered.

Comment: if that is the case then your example appears to be incorrect because you have @ViewChild('TableName') that should be @ViewChild('ttt')  or change <p-table #ttt to <p-table #TableName.  Basically the @ViewChild in your example is not referencing anything in your example