# Angular 4 - PrimeNg DataTableModule - Filter colum by value default

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using primeng for to work with tables.

I have the next column:

```
<p-column field="amount" header="Amount" [sortable]="true" [filter]="true"></p-column>
```

I need to show a default value inside the filter input field, like this:

[image]

Maybe, something similar to:

```
filterValue="100 or variable"
```

And one more thing, it is posible that the filter working ok, but hidding the filter input, this is, because the filter value is obteined from another component.

How could do it?

Comment: This question is quite similar please check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428535/how-to-preset-programmatically-the-filter-value-in-primeng-datatable

Comment: I am investigating your link, thanks